# Why did a moderator delete my answer which I moved from a different question?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer, duplicate-answers

Note, this is not a duplicate question. I did NOT plagiarise my deleted answer in question.

This question is also not a duplicate of 'When to flag an answer as "not an answer"' because a mod flagged my answer. I believe the answer was incorrectly flagged, so raised this question to clarify the context of my flagged answer (details below).

I wrote an answer originally for one question, which was upvoted once and was not based on copy-pasted documentation. After I wrote this answer, I then moved the answer to a more appropriate question, changing the existing answer to point to the new one via a link (I was not aware of this policy at the time).

The edit history of my first answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67596314/revisions), and the deleted (moved) answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601694/4995828).

I wanted to appeal the deletion of my answer since I believe my answer is not plagiarised - I copied my existing answer and set the old answer to link to the new one. Also, the answer is useful because I received upvotes shortly after posting on a low-traffic question.

Can somebody advise me on what to do? I can't cast Undelete votes because a moderator has deleted the new post.

As suggested, I have now deleted the link-only answer, raised a custom mod flag with details. I asked this question because of the character limit enforced in custom mod flag descriptions. I posted this question to link to this post within the flag.

Comment: I suspect this was an automatic flag, and that as you had 2 identical answers, it was flagged. Though, if you think your answer is the same for 2 questions, then vote to close one as the duplicate of the other; don't post link only answers even if they are to a link to another answer you (or someone else) have written on [so]. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596314/2029983) is now a link only answer, and I would personally flag it if I hadn't seen this meta question.

Comment: the second answer is more or less a link-only answer

Comment: Ok, got it. I have now deleted the link-only answer. I didn't realize this was a policy.

Comment: Would we be able to reopen my second answer now?

Comment: just raise a custom flag and explain. and in the future, do not post identical answers to different questions, nor link-only answers.

Comment: Ok, I have done this now. Hopefully, my post can be undeleted soon.

Comment: With respect, the character limit for the custom mod flag didn't have enough characters to explain the whole issue with context from this question so I had to link this question in the custom flag (which I didn't know about before) as well as provide a balanced picture.

Comment: You could always create an unlisted paste bin, and then link to that in the custom mod flag, @PranavKasetti .

Comment: Please do stop editing your post to put phrases in capitals; it comes across as SHOUTING and thus could be seen as rude by users. If you want to add emphasis to words, *italics* and **bold** (though use bold sparingly please), are far better options. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I had to reword the question to include the suggestions I received from the extended discussion in comments. The capitalisation issue is now also fixed, so I believe the question is phrased correctly now. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a moderator deletes a post, only a moderator can undelete the post.

In this case, since the reason for deletion seems to be that one of the answers was wholly copied from another, and you already "solved" the situation by deleting the copied answer, the solution is to raise a custom flag and explain the situation.

500 characters seem more than enough to write something like:

> I believe this answer might have been deleted because it was a copy of this other one, but since I've already deleted/changed that one, I think this one can be undeleted.

**If** that flag is declined, you can always come to meta to ask for more feedback, where both the community and moderators can post longer form answers than what the decline message allows.